# What should I do if my K1 visa was approved, but the photo I submitted was taken more than 6 months ago?

Tags: visas, usa

I got my USA visa(fiance-k-1) approved. But problem is that I gave my passport photo taken before 6 months. I completely forgot that the photo that I have given is the same photo which my fiance used while filing the case. It's already 7 months. Now I am so much in trouble. If I ask the US embassy, they may make issue and can twist my approved visa. If I remain silent then in port of entry there may be the same photos we used in different time period. So, what should I do? Please, suggest me. Should I contact embassy and be honest to them and give new photos? or should i just be silent? Because I don't want any trouble in future. Thank You.

Comment: Has your appearance changed significantly since you took that photo or are you just worried that you do not fulfil the "recent passport photo" rule (Photo should be not be older than 6 months). If it is the former, best to contact the embassy. If it is the latter I suspect (but have no references to back it up) that it won't matter as you already have been issued the visa.

Comment: My appearance has not been changed. I am just worried that that I do not fulfill the recent passport photo rule. I am just worried that may be they have complete documents in port of entry where my fiance has given the same photo. In addition, my fiance has written date on behind of my photo. So, if officer find this out they are clear that the photo that I have given as well as in my passport is clicked in 7-8 months. And they will assume that I told a lie to them. So, please help me.

Comment: @Sarika Just to clarify, your visa was already approved?  You're good to go then, it's not going to be cancelled unless there's a *really* strong reason (like being flagged as an international terrorist, not using a photo a few weeks too old).

Comment: I 99.9% guarantee they wont ask you about the visa photo at border control.

Comment: As long as you have not significantly changed your appearance since taking the photo, you should not worry about it.